# iOS : Way to know if user kill app or device reboot

Tags: ios, background, gps, location, reboot

I just would like to know if there's a way to know in the code when the device reboots and when the user kill the app.

In both way, the `applicationWillTerminate:` method is called.

**Here is my use case** : I'm using the GPS to allow my app running in background. With the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `startMonitoringForRegion` methods, it allows the app to monitor location changes even when restarting device.
As described above, `applicationWillTerminate:` is called (in the same way than rebooting) and if I stop GPS services, the app won't listen location changes after rebooting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS how to detect when app was removed from process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840893/ios-how-to-detect-when-app-was-removed-from-process)

Comment: I have already read this post, and this does not answers my question