# Can we determine that an iOS app was force quit by the user

Tags: ios, push-notification, terminate

When a user force quits an app, some services will stop working, such as background notifications, until the app is re-opened.

Is it possible to detect programatically that the user manually force quit the iOS app from the app switcher, as opposed to the app being terminated naturally by the OS?

Detection either at the time of termination or at the next launch would be sufficient.

Comment: It's possible.. WhatsApp does it when you force-quit too many times.. How they check, I'm not sure  but see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841001/1462718

Answer (score 0):

Use the view controller state saving and restoration mechanism. If the user force-quits your app, state won't be saved, so if you saved something into the state and it isn't there, that's a sign that the app was force-quit.